# Element inside dictionary updated unexpectedly

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python and I just encounter some strange behaviour about dicts when I try to do the Advent of Code (AoC) 2021_Dec_01 question.

The AoC question is like this:
A txt file contains the following element is given

```
199
200
208
210
200
207
240
269
260
263
```

If the element is greater than the previous one, set to increased. If it is smaller than the previous one set decreased. So it should become:

```
199 (N/A - no previous measurement)
200 (increased)
208 (increased)
210 (increased)
200 (decreased)
207 (increased)
240 (increased)
269 (increased)
260 (decreased)
263 (increased)
```

I try to convert the above file into a list, than create an dictionary from it:

```
try:
   with open("test.txt", "r") as depths:
       # Create a list for depths and clear "\n after each words"
       depths_list = []
       for x in depths:
           depths_list.append(x.rstrip())
       print(depths_list)
       # depths_list = ['199', '200', '208', '210', '200', '207', '240', '269', '260', '263']
       
       # Create a dict to store {depth : increased/decreased} data
       i = 0
       depths_dict = {}
       for depth in depths_list: 
           if i == 0:
               depths_dict[depth] = "(N/A - no previous measurement)"
           elif depth > depths_list[i-1]:
               depths_dict[depth] = "(increased)"
           elif depth < depths_list[i-1]:                
               depths_dict[depth] = "(decreased)"
           i+=1
       print(depths_dict) #Add this for debugging

except Exception as e:
   print(f"ERROR FOUND: {e}")
```

I added a `print(depths_dict)` for debugging, the output surprises me and I am quite confusing about what is happening.

below is the output:

```
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(increased)', '208': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(increased)', '208': '(increased)', '210': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(decreased)', '208': '(increased)', '210': '(increased)', '207': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(decreased)', '208': '(increased)', '210': '(increased)', '207': '(increased)', '240': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(decreased)', '208': '(increased)', '210': '(increased)', '207': '(increased)', '240': '(increased)', '269': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(decreased)', '208': '(increased)', '210': '(increased)', '207': '(increased)', '240': '(increased)', '269': '(increased)', '260': '(decreased)', '263': '(increased)'}
{'199': '(N/A - no previous measurement', '200': '(decreased)', '208': '(increased)', '210': '(increased)', '207': '(increased)', '240': '(increased)', '269': '(increased)', '260': '(decreased)', '263': '(increased)'}
```

As shown above, the second element in the dict `{200:(increased)}` suddenly changed from increased to decrease after the 3rd iteration.

What is happening there? How come the value of `depths_dict[200]` is changed which I haven't done anything like `depths_dict[200] = sth`?

Comment: The problem is that you are reassigning new values to the same key in your loops.

Comment: This is not surprising. There two rows in the file with the value `200`... Are you aware that dicts can only have unique keys? So when the second 200 is encountered it simply updates the first, doesn't create a new entry. A dict is simply not the write structure for this task...

Comment: @yivi I did as soon as I was are of the meta discussion. Did not know about the meta tag convention.

Comment: You (not at any one specific) could start first with some useful input before closing questions, deleting comments and distributing down votes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact you are reassigning new values to existing keys. You will need to change the way you process your data. Here a suggestion:

```
# picking up your parse data:
l = ['199', '200', '208', '210', '200', '207', '240', '269', '260', '263']
trend = ['NA']  # a container to store trends, start with no change ('NA')
# iterate through your data
for i in range(1, len(l)):  # start at the second element 
    if int(l[i]) - int(l[i - 1]) > 0:
        trend.append('(increased)')
    elif int(l[i]) - int(l[i - 1]) < 0:
        trend.append('(decreased)')
    else:
        trend.append('(no change)')

# maybe you want a dictionary of the positions/values and the trend now?
d = {(i, val): trend_val for (i, val), trend_val in zip(enumerate(l), trend)}

d
{(0, '199'): 'NA',
 (1, '200'): '(increased)',
 (2, '208'): '(increased)',
 (3, '210'): '(increased)',
 (4, '200'): '(decreased)',
 (5, '207'): '(increased)',
 (6, '240'): '(increased)',
 (7, '269'): '(increased)',
 (8, '260'): '(decreased)',
 (9, '263'): '(increased)'}
```

But yet a cleaner way to do this is to use pandas:

```
l = ['199', '200', '208', '210', '200', '207', '240', '269', '260', '263']
l = [int(x) for x in l]
s = pd.Series(l)
def decision(x):
    if x > 0:
        return '(increased)'
    if x < 0:
        return '(decreased)'
    return '(no change)'

data = s.diff().apply(lambda x: decision(x))

data
0    (no change)
1    (increased)
2    (increased)
3    (increased)
4    (decreased)
5    (increased)
6    (increased)
7    (increased)
8    (decreased)
9    (increased)
dtype: object
```

From here on you could build anything like via `data.to_dict()`